# Delete NA data ,but with certain condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's see example data

```
nad=structure(list(x1 = 1:5, x2 = c(NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 34L), x3 = c(NA, 
1L, NA, NA, NA), x4 = c(NA, 2L, 5L, NA, NA), x5 = c(NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA), x6 = c(NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", 
"x3", "x4", "x5", "x6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
2  2  2  1  2  3  4
3  3  2 NA  5 NA NA
4  4 NA NA NA NA NA
5  5 34 NA NA NA NA
```

Usually to get complete data without `NA`, i can use this function

```
na.omit(nad)
```

But my problem a little complex.
In spite of the fact that `x2` has `NA`, i do not need delete row where there are `NA` for `x2`.
Valuable data is  where there is value for `x1` and not in `x2`,
and if there are observations in the row for `x1` and `x2` but not on the another variables, then the row should not be deleted.
Therefore, the first and 4th rows should not be deleted.
3 and 5 should be deleted, because here, on the one hand there are observations on `x1` and `x2`, but other variables are blank.
Second row is completely complete, i do not need to delete it.
How can I delete `NA` using such condition?
Desired output

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
2  2  2  1  2  3  4
3  4 NA NA NA NA NA
```

As an addition(separately question, but adjacent), I also want to ask here, maybe I will  need this for analytics
if there is such situation

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
2  2 NA  1  1  1  1
```

Here first row has `NA` for `x2`, and `NA` for other variables,
and second row has `NA` for `x2`,but another variable is not NA.
How in such case, left only rows where `x1` has value, `x2` doesn't have, but another variable have values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So maybe you are looking for

```
nad[!is.na(nad$x1) & is.na(nad$x2) | rowSums(!is.na(nad)) == ncol(nad), ]

#  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
#1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
#2  2  2  1  2  3  4
#4  4 NA NA NA NA NA
```

This selects rows where `x1` has non-NA values and `x2` has `NA` OR all the values in the row are non-NA.

Comment: what about subquestion  As an addition(separately question, but adjacent), I also want to ask here, maybe I will need this for analytics if there is such situation

  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
2  2 NA  1  1  1  1

Here first row has NA for x2, and NA for other variables, and second row has NA for x2,but another variable is not NA. How in such case, left only rows where x1 has value, x2 doesn't have, but another variable have values?

Comment: How to comply with this condition?

Comment: @Kogan Do you mean something like `nad[!is.na(nad$x1) & is.na(nad$x2) & rowSums(is.na(nad[-(1:2)])) %in% c(0, ncol(nad) - 2), ]` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you would probably be best off by checking each row wether it satisfies your conditions. If I understood correctly, something like the following could work:

```
keep <- apply(nad, 1, function(row) {
  # Don't keep data if first column is NA
  if (!is.na(row[[1]])) {
    sumna <- sum(is.na(row[-1]))
    # Only keep if rest is all NA or none is NA
    if (sumna == 0 | sumna == length(row) - 1) {
      return(TRUE)
    } else {
      return(FALSE)
    }
  } else {
    return(FALSE)
  }
})

nad[keep,]
```

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
2  2  2  1  2  3  4
4  4 NA NA NA NA NA
```